# Need to hide a div when an option is selected by a HTML dropdown list

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

At the moment, I have a page where a client enters job data. There is an option to say whether their client has agreed to the job sheet data or not:

```
<div id="modalwindow">
    <div class="leftcolumn">
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->create('Jobsheet', array(
                'class' => 'form-horizontal',
                'id' => 'addquickJobsheet'
            ));

            echo $this->Form->input('jobnum', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'lable' => 'Job ID',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter the job ID here'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('jobdate', array(
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Date',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'placeholder' => 'YYYY/MM/DD'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('siteaddress', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => $sites['Siteaddress']['id']
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('bins', array(
                'label' => 'Bins',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter the number of bins here'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('company', array(
                'value' => $companyid,
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'label' => 'Company',
                'class' => 'span5'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('driverid', array(
                'options' => $driverselect,
                'empty' => 'Select Driver',
                'label' => 'Driver',
                'class' => 'span5'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('vehicleid', array(
                'options' => $vehicleselect,
                'empty' => 'Select Vehicle',
                'label' => 'Vehicle',
                'class' => 'span5'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->input('contract', array(
                'value' => $contractid,
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'label' => 'Contract',
                'class' => 'span5'
            ));
        ?>
    </div>
    <div class="rightcolumn">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('skipsize', array(
                'options' => $skipsizes,
                'empty' => 'Select Skip Size',
                'label' => 'Skip Size',
                'class' => 'span5'
            ));
            $ao = array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No');
            echo $this->Form->input('recweight', array(
                'label' => 'Weight Of Skip',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter the weight here'
            ));
            $agval = array('1' => 'Yes', '0' => 'No');
            echo $this->Form->input('agreed', array(
                'label' => 'Agreed?',
                'options' => $agval,
                'class' => 'span5',
                'value' => '1'
            ));
        ?>
        <div id="agreedby">
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('agreedby', array(
                'label' => 'Agreed By',
                'class' => 'span5',
                'placeholder' => 'Enter who agreed this job sheet here'
            ));
        ?>
        </div>
        <?php
            echo $this->Form->input('deleted', array(
                'type' => 'hidden',
                'value' => '0'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->submit('Next', array(
                'class' => 'btn btn-primary'
            ));
            echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

At the moment, I have Javscript that is supposed to hide the "agreedby" field if the job sheet hasn't been agreed:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#JobsheetAgreed").change(function() {
        ($(this).val() == "0") ({
            $("#agreedby").hide();  
        });
        ($(this).val() == "1") ({
            $("#agreedby").show();
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

But this doesn't seem to do anything. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It should be generating some errors in your JavaScript console.

Comment: Does your framework include `id="xyz"` for your form fields, or is it just `name="xyz"`? If it is the latter, the `#xyz` selector obviously won't work.

Comment: Please post the generated HTML and not the PHP.

Comment: Where is the input element "#JobsheetAgreed" and what its type is it any checkbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure where `#JobsheetAgreed` is in the HTML, does that even exist ? You may also try checking your HTML and the IDs.

Anyway, I think this code should work if the selectors are correct.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#JobsheetAgreed").change(function() {
    var agrdby = $(this).val();
       if (agrdby == "0") {
       $("#agreedby").hide();
       }
       else {
       $("#agreedby").show();
       } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked first time. `#JobsheetAgreed` is generated by the framework as the form's ID. Sorry, I should've said.

Comment: That's amazing ! And I was thinking that the id might have been generated from the server side framework. But just to make sure I asked you to check the selectors :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#agreedby, [name="agreedby"]').hide();
```

instead of

```
$("#agreedby").hide();
```

It could be because the PHP framework you are using does not include the ID attribute for your form fields.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find you defining the id "JobsheetAgreed" at any input element, most likely that'd be the cause if you're not just skipping some fragments of your code.

Assuming this is the part :

```
echo $this->Form->input('agreed', array(
            'label' => 'Agreed?',
            'options' => $agval,
            'class' => 'span5',
            'value' => '1'
        ));
```

There'd have to be a `'id' => 'JobsheetAgreed'` in that as far as I can read your code.